# Sencha touch links not clickable on a phone

Tags: android, hyperlink, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm doing a sencha touch / phonegap app for Android. i have a very simple problem with links in a TabPanel: they are not clickable on the phone.

I'm using sencha touch version 2.0 rc2 so maybe that's the problem. I'm about to go to version  1.1 to see if it's any better.

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Sencha',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create("Ext.TabPanel", {
      fullscreen: true,
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      ui: 'light',

      items: [
        {
          title: 'Home',
          iconCls: 'home',
          html: [
            '<br><br>',
            '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'clicked!\');">click me</a>',
            '<br><br>',
            '<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">or me</a>',
          ].join('')
        }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Should be nice and simple, right?

**Update**

It works on 1.1.1. what a shame, because i heard 2.0 was much faster for android. but if a simple thing like this is broken, there's no chance i can use it.

where do i go to log a bug?

Comment: You are probably better off asking your question on the Sencha forums http://www.sencha.com/forum/

Comment: maybe a little off-topic, but wouldn't it be better to use buttons instead of html to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

```
obj(your first item obj).getEl().on('tap',your function, null, {delegate: 'a:first-child'});
```

Answer (score 0):

onClick events are not fired on iPhone, use onTouchStart instead and it will work.